# Android ListView and SimpleCursosrAdapter: nothing is showed

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

A read a lot of docs, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I'm just trying to load data with Cursor and show it in a ListView using SimpleCursorAdapter.Here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_expense_category);
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String q = "SELECT rowid as _id, " + GLO.DBEntry_Categories.COLUMN_CATEGORY +
            " FROM " + GLO.DBEntry_Categories.TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(q, new String[]{});
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Read count: " + Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()) + " " + cursor.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    //TODO: use Loader
    String[] fromCols = {GLO.DBEntry_Categories.COLUMN_CATEGORY};
    int[] toViews = {R.id.MyTextView1};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor,
            fromCols, toViews, 0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SelectExpenseCategory_list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

So toast message shows there are 3 items in cursor, and data is peresent (at least in first one, but I'm sure for others too). But nothing is showed in ListView.

Here is a part of my activity layout:

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/SelectExpenseCategory_search"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/SelectExpenseCategory_list">
</ListView>
```

And here is complete file for item layout:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MyTextView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/cm_dark_green"
    android:textSize="24sp">
</TextView>
```

Any ideas what's wrong?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the internal layout for the list items: `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

The `TextView` id there is called `text1`, so instead use this:

```
int[] toViews = {android.R.id.text1};
```

If you want to use your own custom layout then change the layout used by your adapter to e.g. `R.layout.list_item_layout`.

Comment: I changed toViews to internal id as you suggested, but nothing changed. There's still nothing in my ListView :(

Comment: Yes. I changed it to show number of all entries and contents of the first two entries, and it shows there are 4 entries in DB and first two has a value

Comment: Well, your answer was correct =) I realized light-gray on white was completely invisible in 320x200 in my emulator =)